# MariaDB: IF-THEN-ELSE Statement in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, procedural-programming

Anyone who can help on how to apply MariaDB: IF-THEN-ELSE Statement in PHP.

I want to query when the account type is Admin and he/she created the data in pre_registered table  the Cancelled status also display in the list but if he/she is Admin but not the on who created the data it will not display on the list. If normal user is logged in the system, the Cancelled status will not be included in the list.

I have try the below query but did not work.

```
<?php
     $account_type = getActiveAccountType($connect);

     $query = "SELECT * FROM pre_registered WHERE ";

    if ($account_type == 'Admin') {
        $query .= "
        
        IF registered_created_by != ".$_SESSION['account_id']." THEN
        {
            registered_status != 'Cancelled'
        }
        END IF;
        
        ";
    } else if ($account_type == 'User') {
        $query .= "
            registered_status != 'Cancelled'
        ";
    }
```

Comment: This is not how it works, you are mixing PHP and SQL

Comment: How can I get the same result with SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You want `registered_status != 'Cancelled'` in regardless of the user type, so include this in `$query`.

For the admin user, you want to include results with `registered_created_by =  $account_id`. So in this PHP `if` branch. Because its an `OR` condition, it will be included regardless of the `registered_status`.

```
$query .= ' OR registered_created_by = ?'
```

When executing this query as a prepared query, pass `$_SESSION['account_id']` as the value to be used in the query.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to programming as well, but I hope this helps.

Try getting the results first and write a condition that checks if registered_created_by == $_SESSION['account_id'], then show the column if it does and hide if it doesnt.

Comment: Please read S.O. guidelines, this is not a forum. You should edit your question, not put more information as answer. I will suggest you still learning before ask because this question is too broad

Comment: This was not my question though..

Comment: Is not a great answer as it is a little vague. Also database are very good at filtering data so using their strength is a good way to learn database and php by leveraging each for its strengths. Welcome to SO. Please do continue to give answers. A disclaimer on your experience is ok, do ensure the detail is enough to give a novice user however.